# How to rewrite de remote address received by Apache/PHP server when it is behind an Nginx reverse proxy using Apache remoteip?

Tags: networking, apache-2.4, docker

I have an Apache 2.4 with PHP 5.4 application using extensive use of `SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

The infrastructure is going through changes and recently we deployed an Nginx acting as reverse proxy. The proxy is properly adding `X-Real-IP` and `X-Forwarded-For` headers, both showing the real client IP. For portability, we have also containerized both the Apache/PHP application and the Nginx proxy. They are deployed in two different hosts that communicate to each other through external IPs (will be changed to a private network in the future).

I cannot modify the application, but I can modify the Apache configuration.

I have enabled remoteip module, which is a replacement for mod_rpaf. I have tried several configurations such as:

```
RemoteIPProxiesHeader X-Forwarded-For
RemoteIPInternalProxy <external ip of the proxy>
```

Or

```
RemoteIPProxiesHeader X-Forwarded-For
RemoteIPTrustedProxy <external ip of the proxy>
```

And some combinations of the `~Proxy`variables.

In any case, when running `phpinfo()` I get the following output:

```
HTTP_X_REAL_IP          <my real client ip>
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR    <my real client ip>
SERVER_ADDR             <the Apache/PHP docker machine's ip>
REMOTE_ADDR             <external ip of the proxy>
```

Any idea on how to properly configure the the remoteip module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the remoteip module shipped with Apache 2.4 doesn't work. I grabbed the last stable version (v0.8.4) of mod_rpaf from Github. Compiled and installed modifying the default configuration as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rpaf.c>
  RPAF_Enable       On
  RPAF_ProxyIPs     <external ip of the proxy>
  RPAF_Header       X-Forwarded-For
  RPAF_SetHostName  On
  RPAF_SetHTTPS     On
  RPAF_SetPort      On
</IfModule>
```

And it worked like charm.